# [Clang Checker]how to get the class name of a method?

Tags: ios, clang

I want to add a new clang checker to my clang static analyzer. The checker can get the method name, class name, and framework name where the method is called.

now i can only get the name of the method using the api "getNameStart()" , how can i know the class name when a method is called?  and how can i get the framework name?

Look forward to your kind reply...

---------------------------here is the api i use to get the method name:

```
    void DemoChecker::checkPreStmt(const CallExpr *CE, CheckerContext &C) const { 
    const ProgramStateRef state = C.getState(); 
    const LocationContext *LC = C.getLocationContext(); 
    const Expr *Callee = CE->getCallee(); 
    const FunctionDecl *FD = state->getSVal(Callee, LC).getAsFunctionDecl(); 

    if (!FD) 
            return; 

    std::cout << "***** FD->getNameAsString() *****>>" << FD->getNameAsString() << endl;
```